# Hibernate - How can i perform UNION and return a LIST of items?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, union

How can i run a UNION query in hibernate.
I'm new to learning hibernate and now i have a named query like this,

```
<query>
    SELECT product.defaultSk.name FROM Product product
    WHERE product.defaultSk.name LIKE :name 
    AND product.defaultSk.activeStartDate &lt;= :currentDate
    AND (product.defaultSk.activeEndDate &gt; :currentDate OR product.defaultSk.activeEndDate = null)
    AND (product.archiveStatus.archived IS NULL OR product.archiveStatus.archived = 'N')        
    UNION
    SELECT category.name FROM Category category
    WHERE category.name LIKE :name
    AND (archived = 'N')
</query>
```

When i execute the above query, I'm getting the result for only the first query and my second query is not returning any results..
My console shows only the triggering of the first query and i cant find the second query being fired.Why does it not run the second query...

This my console after running the query,

CONSOLE:

```
 Hibernate: select skimpl1_.NAME as col_0_0_ from PRODUCT productimp0_, BLC_SK skimpl1_ left outer join PRODUCT_SK_XREF skimpl1_1_ on skimpl1_.SK_ID=skimpl1_1_.SK_ID where productimp0_.DEFAULT_SK_ID=skuimpl1_.SK_ID and (skimpl1_.NAME like ?) and skimpl1_.ACTIVE_START_DATE<=? and (skimpl1_.ACTIVE_END_DATE>? or skimpl1_.ACTIVE_END_DATE is null) and (productimp0_.ARCHIVED is null or productimp0_.ARCHIVED='N')
```

I have implemented the jquery autocomplete to yeild results from a table and now that i want to merge two table results.I m going with the union query as it merges the result from  two tables.
Am i doing something wrong..
I have read some SO posts that union is not possible in Hibernate.
If so what will be the workaround for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HQL doesn't support `union`. You'll have to execute two different queries, or use SQL.